# Accessing Terraform variables within user_data provider template file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am launching an `aws_launch_configuration` instance using terraform.

I'm using a shell script for the `user_data` variable, like so:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_config" {
    ...
    user_data = "${file("router-init.sh")}"
    ...  
}
```

Within this `router-init.sh`, one of the things I would like to do is to have access to the IP addresses for other instances I am launching via terraform.

I know that I can use a splat to access all the IP addresses of that instance, for instance:

```
output ip_address {
    value = ${aws_instance.myAWSInstance.*.private_ip}"
}
```

Is there a way to pass/access these IP addresses within the `router-init.sh` script?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using a [`template_file` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html):

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("router-init.sh.tpl")}"

  vars = {
    some_address = "${aws_instance.some.private_ip}"
  }
}
```

Then reference it inside the template like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SOME_ADDRESS = ${some_address}" > /tmp/
```

Then use that for the `user_data`:

```
 user_data = ${data.template_file.init.rendered}
```

Comment: Is that possible when you are relying on the output of the instances being created? I'd expect this to be a cyclical dependency where the user data needs to know the output of the IP address of itself plus other instances being created at the same time (via `count`).

Comment: Ack, nevermind, just realised the LC wants to know about some different AWS instances that are not in an ASG. Odd use case but yeah that will work.

Comment: Yeah the dependency can be difficult but you can have resources depend on another more explicitly using depends_on. If it needs to know its ip you could pull that from within the instance itself.

Comment: Thanks very much! I have implemented this and it works.

Comment: I think the second line should be:
template = "${file("router-init.sh.tpl")}"

Comment: Correct @rezler, not sure how I managed to include some extra characters. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 18):

For people coming here since Terraform 0.12 and later, the [templatefile function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) should be used instead of using template_file resource, so for the example in the question, it would be something like

```
locals {
  vars = {
    some_address = aws_instance.some.private_ip
  }
}

user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/router-init.sh", local.vars))
```

Answer (score 5):

From Terraform 0.12 and later, you can use the templatefile function instead of the template_file resource, so for a general use case where you need to access more than one variable, you can use:

```
    locals {
      variable1       = "your_username"
      variable2       = "your_password"
      db_address      = aws_db_instance.some-db.address
      public_alb_dns  = aws_lb.some-alb.dns_name
    }
    
    resource "aws_instance" "web_01" {
      ....
      user_data = base64encode(templatefile("user_data.sh", {
        db_address      = local.db_address
        admin_user      = local.variable1
        admin_password  = local.variable2
        public_alb_dns  = local.private_alb_dns
      } ))
      ....
    }
```

You can also access other terraform resource attribute references.