# Read an external file which contains a variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm deploying a `google_compute_instance` with Terraform. That instance should run a script when its created. Using the property `metadata_startup_script`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "couchbase_host" {
   ...

   metadata_startup_script = file("vm_setup.sh")
}
```

Where `vm_setup.sh`:

```
program --arg ${var.my_value}
```

`file()` extracts to a raw string, meaning the variable is not populated. How can I use a terraform variable in my `.sh`? I'm trying to avoid heredoc `<< EOF ..` because my script is somewhat long.

Comment: Yes, its possible. I have Deleted an answer i had posted. There is an existing Post that has the answer for TF 12 and earlier version..  Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835636/accessing-terraform-variables-within-user-data-provider-template-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) is similar to [the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) in that it reads a given file from disk, but it also additionally interprets the contents of the file as a [string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates), so you can insert external values into it.

For example:

```
   metadata_startup_script = templatefile("${path.module}/vm_setup.sh.tmpl", {
     arg_value = var.my_value
   })
```

In the template file you can use `${arg_value}` to substitute the given value from the object in the second argument to `templatefile`.

---

Please note that with just a direct reference to the value the result will not necessarily be valid shell syntax -- the caller could potentially set `var.my_value` to something that would be misinterpreted by the shell. One way to avoid that would be to use [the `replace` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/replace.html) to apply single-quoting to the value, assuming this script will ultimately be evaluated by a Unix-style shell (bash, etc):

```
program --arg '${replace(arg_value, "'", "'\\''")}'
```

If `arg_value` had the value `I'm a troublemaker` then the above template would produce the following result:

```
program --arg 'I'\''m a troublemaker'
```

...where the surrounding `'` quote characters and the special escaping of the `'` in the string should cause the shell to interpret the value literally, exactly as provided by the caller of your module.